# problem with PHP RSA encryption using public key return nothing

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I have problem with $public_key in RSA encryption 
and i receive empty result no error

I am using phpseclib

Example:

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$plaintext = 'test test';

$public_key = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----';


$rsa->loadKey($public_key);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
echo $ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);


var_dump($rsa->encrypt($plaintext));
```

---

but if I change key to this one:

```
$rsa->loadKey('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SdPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');
```

than it is working.
What is wrong with first key ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The first key isn't a key - it's an X.509 cert. To encrypt something with the public key contained within an X.509 cert you'd need to use `File_X509`. Something like this (untested):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509('...');
$rsa = $x509->getPublicKey();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
echo $ciphertext;
```